# вставка фразы в url

Tags: android, url

Смысл заключается в том, что из editText в URL после text= вставляется слово/фраза для перевода. Если вставляю одно слово, то все хорошо, но если пишу фразу, то используется только первое слово.
Запрос из POSTMAN:

> https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/Minicard?text=long
>   phrase&srcLang=1033&dstLang=1049

Ответ:

```
{
    "SourceLanguage": 1033,
    "TargetLanguage": 1049,
    "Heading": "long",
    "Translation": {
        "Heading": "long",
        "Translation": "длинный; больше своей ширины"
}
}
```

Как можно увидеть, то переводится только первое слово.
В ссылке пробовал писать:
https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/Minicard?text=**long%20phrase**&srcLang=1033&dstLang=1049
https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/Minicard?text=**long&phrase**&srcLang=1033&dstLang=1049 и различные вариации тоже самое.
Подскажите, что не так?

Формирую Url следующим образом:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("https")
            .authority("developers.lingvolive.com")
            .appendPath("api")
            .appendPath("v1")
            .appendPath("Minicard")
            .appendQueryParameter("text", word.getText().toString())
            .appendQueryParameter("srcLang", "1033")
            .appendQueryParameter("dstLang", "1049");
   String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
```

**UPD:**
Все было правильно сделано, просто особенность словарей Abbyy Lingvo в том, что отсутствуут большая часть словосочетаний, которые я пытался использовать.

Comment: Может не в пробеле дело? - это не единственный символ, который нельзя передавать в url-строке некодированным. Вы пробовали сформировать строку запроса с помощью `Uri.Bilder`, как вам уже советовали? - он сам всё закодирует как надо.

Comment: с Uri.Builder'ом тоже самое